# Show Is Not A Function At HTMLButtonElement Error

Tags: javascript, html, mdc

I am following [this codepen](https://codepen.io/j-o-d-o/pen/XZqNYy?editors=1010) which works perfectly. I took the code from it and put it in my local HTML file and added the JS. However when I run it locally it doesn't work. The console prints out the following message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dialogLogin.show is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

My HTML & JS code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Auth.X</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>How can I use several dialogs on the same website?</h1>
<h2>https://material.io/components/web/catalog/dialogs/</h2>

<!-- Trigger Dialogs -->
<button id="dialog-login">Open Login Dialog</button><br><br>
<button id="dialog-delivery">Open Delivery Dialog</button>

<!-- Dialogs: Login -->
<aside id="mdc-dialog-login"
       class="mdc-dialog"
       role="alertdialog"
       aria-labelledby="mdc-dialog-login-label"
       aria-describedby="mdc-dialog-login-description">
    <div class="mdc-dialog__surface">
        <header class="mdc-dialog__header">
            <h2 id="mdc-dialog-login-label" class="mdc-dialog__header__title">
                Login
            </h2>
        </header>
        <section id="mdc-dialog-login-description" class="mdc-dialog__body">
            [LOGIN FORM]
        </section>
        <footer class="mdc-dialog__footer">
            <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-dialog__footer__button mdc-dialog__footer__button--accept">RegisteR</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-dialog__backdrop"></div>
</aside>

<!-- Dialogs: Delivery -->
<aside id="mdc-dialog-delivery-condition"
       class="mdc-dialog js--mdc-delivery-condition"
       role="alertdialog"
       aria-labelledby="mdc-delivery-condition-label"
       aria-describedby="mdc-delivery-condition-description">
    <div class="mdc-dialog__surface">
        <header class="mdc-dialog__header">
            <h2 id="mdc-delivery-condition-label" class="mdc-dialog__header__title">
                [Delivery]
            </h2>
        </header>
        <section id="mdc-delivery-condition-description" class="mdc-dialog__body">
            [TEXT]
        </section>
        <footer class="mdc-dialog__footer">
            <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Close</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-dialog__backdrop"></div>
</aside>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Find all the dialogs on the page
const dialogLoginEle = document.getElementById('mdc-dialog-login');
const dialogLogin = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(dialogLoginEle);
dialogLogin.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
  console.log('accepted login');
});
dialogLogin.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
  console.log('canceled login');
});

const dialogDeliveryEle = document.getElementById('mdc-dialog-delivery-condition');
const dialogDelivery = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(dialogDeliveryEle);
dialogDelivery.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
  console.log('accepted delivery');
});
dialogDelivery.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
  console.log('canceled delivery');
});

document.querySelector('#dialog-login').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogLogin.show();
});
document.querySelector('#dialog-delivery').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogDelivery.show();
});


</script>

</body>
```

Why does this not work locally?

**UPDATE**
As per my comment, version 0.28 of the MDC Javascript works with this code. The dialog boxes appear. So the question now is, in the latest version of the MDC Javascript how is this supposed to work?

Comment: I've made some progress with this. I am using the latest version of the MDC CSS and JS but that doesn't seem to be compatible. If I choose the following version explicitly `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/material-components-web@0.28.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css` then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the guys on the MDC Discord channel, it appears that .show() was replaced with .open().

Answer (score 0):

**In the codepan you have used the version 0.28.
Here is the example with the latest version.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Auth.X</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<h1>How can I use several dialogs on the same website?</h1>
<h2>https://material.io/components/web/catalog/dialogs/</h2>

<!-- Trigger Dialogs -->
<button id="dialog-login">Open Login Dialog</button><br><br>
<button id="dialog-delivery">Open Delivery Dialog</button>

<!-- Dialogs: Login -->
<aside id="mdc-dialog-login"
       class="mdc-dialog"
       role="alertdialog"
       aria-labelledby="mdc-dialog-login-label"
       aria-describedby="mdc-dialog-login-description">
    <div class="mdc-dialog__surface">
        <header class="mdc-dialog__header">
            <h2 id="mdc-dialog-login-label" class="mdc-dialog__header__title">
                Login
            </h2>
        </header>
        <section id="mdc-dialog-login-description" class="mdc-dialog__body">
            [LOGIN FORM]
        </section>
        <footer class="mdc-dialog__footer">
            <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-dialog__footer__button mdc-dialog__footer__button--accept">RegisteR</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-dialog__backdrop"></div>
</aside>

<!-- Dialogs: Delivery -->
<aside id="mdc-dialog-delivery-condition"
       class="mdc-dialog js--mdc-delivery-condition"
       role="alertdialog"
       aria-labelledby="mdc-delivery-condition-label"
       aria-describedby="mdc-delivery-condition-description">
    <div class="mdc-dialog__surface">
        <header class="mdc-dialog__header">
            <h2 id="mdc-delivery-condition-label" class="mdc-dialog__header__title">
                [Delivery]
            </h2>
        </header>
        <section id="mdc-delivery-condition-description" class="mdc-dialog__body">
            [TEXT]
        </section>
        <footer class="mdc-dialog__footer">
            <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__footer__button--cancel">Close</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-dialog__backdrop"></div>
</aside>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // Find all the dialogs on the page
const dialogLoginEle = document.getElementById('mdc-dialog-login');
const dialogLogin = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(dialogLoginEle);
dialogLogin.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
  console.log('accepted login');
});
dialogLogin.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
  console.log('canceled login');
});

const dialogDeliveryEle = document.getElementById('mdc-dialog-delivery-condition');
const dialogDelivery = new mdc.dialog.MDCDialog(dialogDeliveryEle);
dialogDelivery.listen('MDCDialog:accept', function() {
  console.log('accepted delivery');
});
dialogDelivery.listen('MDCDialog:cancel', function() {
  console.log('canceled delivery');
});

document.querySelector('#dialog-login').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogLogin.open();
});
document.querySelector('#dialog-delivery').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  dialogDelivery.open();
});


</script>

</body>
```